# Clicking on anchor tag will only excute part of a function

Tags: javascript, html, async-await, fetch

I am currently facing an issue where I have event listeners running for my client's website which track all hover and clicks on the website. We have 4 clients and our code works fine on 3 of them but it does not work correctly on the 1 client's website.

We are running the following code when a click is triggered:

```
async function objectClick(obj) {
  var tag = obj.target;
  if (tag.nodeName == 'IMG') {
    objectName = tag.src;
  } else {
    objectName = tag.innerText || tag.textContent || tag.value;
  }

  var data_tag = tag.getAttribute("data-*");

  if (data_tag != null) {
    if (data_tag.includes("abc")) {
      var layout = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(page));
      layout.ctr = 1;
      window.localStorage.setItem(page, JSON.stringify(layout))
      await sendToHistory(uid, url, JSON.stringify(layout));
    } else if (data_tag.includes("reward")) {
      var layout = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(page));
      layout.reward = 1;
      window.localStorage.setItem(page, JSON.stringify(layout))
      await sendToHistory(uid, url, JSON.stringify(layout));
    }
  }


  if (data_tag === "abc" || data_tag === "reward") {
    await sendToJourney(uid, "Clicked", -1, tag.nodeName, JSON.stringify({ text: objectName, data_nostra: null }), url, page);

  } else {
    await sendToJourney(uid, "Clicked", -1, tag.nodeName, JSON.stringify({ text: objectName, data_nostra: data_nostra_tag }), url, page);

  }

}
```

For most of our clients, all the code runs in the function runs, including the `sendToJourney` function. For this client, after `sendToHistory` runs, the page switches and `sendToJourney` is not triggered. Do you know why this is?

`sendToJourney` and `sendToHistory` are functions that send some data to an API. Let me know if you need more information. Lastly, the client's website is created using Elementor which is a WordPress plugin. 2 of the other 4 clients also use Elementor but the function is fully executed for them but just not for this 1 client. Is there something that can be preventing the code from fully executing?

We have tried using obj.preventDefault but we cannot get the event to be triggered afterwards once our code is executed so what solution could be use here?

I call objectClick() by attaching an event listener as such:

```
(async function (document) {
  await initData()
  var trackable = document.querySelectorAll("img,button,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,a,span,input[type='submit'],[data-*]");
  for (var i = 0; i < trackable.length; i++) {
    trackable[i].addEventListener('mouseover', onHover, false);
    trackable[i].addEventListener('mouseout', offHover, false);
    trackable[i].addEventListener('click', objectClick, false);
  }
})(document);
```

Comment: How are you calling `objectClick()`?

Comment: I am editing the post to add the code @Barmar

Comment: `obj.preventDefault()` should do it.

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned in the post that we tried using it already. I accidentally said `We have tried using event.preventDefault`, I mean `obj.preventDefault`.

Comment: We used it and it partially worked but after we do that, how do we undo the `obj.preventDefault`?

Comment: You can't undo it. Either you want to follow the link or you don't.

Comment: Can you send the "sendToHistory" function?